# With Moment.js - what is the best way to display a duration with modified locale data alongside a duration with default locale data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Essentially I need to display:

> "Runs every minute"

which has modified locale data to use "minute" instead of "a minute"

AND

> "Will run again in a minute"

which has default locale data, in the same Component.

#### The updated locale I need:

```js
  moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime: {
      future: 'in %s',
      past: '%s ago',
      s: 'few seconds',
      ss: '%d seconds',
      m: 'minute',
      mm: '%d minutes',
      h: 'hour',
      hh: '%d hours',
      d: 'day',
      dd: '%d days',
      M: 'month',
      MM: '%d months',
      y: 'year',
      yy: '%d years'
    }
  });
```

### What I think I know:

`moment.duration` only supports language locale updates and does not have access to the full locale object. So I can't update locale like `moment.duration.locale('en', localeUpdates)`.

A `moment()` instance does not have access to `.duration`. So I can't say

```js
const mod = moment();
mod.updateLocale('en', localeUpdates);

mod.duration(timestamp);
```

### As a result

Any attempt to display BOTH of the durations above fail, because the only way to update `duration` locale is globally.

Is there a way forward here that doesn't involve regex?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/momentjs-ejmb6?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more digging I found you can create a custom locale, which Duration can then use.

More info here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/

So you would define your custom locale like

```js
import moment from 'moment';

moment.defineLocale('en-modified', {
  parentLocale: 'en',
  relativeTime: {
    future: 'in %s',
    past: '%s ago',
    s: 'few seconds',
    ss: '%ds',
    m: '%dm',
    mm: '%dm',
    h: '%dhr',
    hh: '%dhr',
    d: '%dd',
    dd: '%dd',
    M: '%dmo',
    MM: '%dmo',
    y: '%dyr',
    yy: '%dyr'
  }
});

export default moment;
```

And then use it like

```js
moment.duration.locale('en-modified')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately locale and `humanize()` function doesn't solve everything and you have to create custom format function. As a another workaround `moment().duration().valueOf()` returns [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) so you can find api which processes that to human readable format or again create one.

```js
const format = (momentObject, options) => {
  let text = momentObject.humanize();

  if (!options) {
    return text;
  }

  if (!options.withDeterminer) {
    if (momentObject === "PT1M") {
      return "minute"
    }

    return text.replace(/a\s/g, '');
  }
}

const result1 = format(moment.duration(1, "minutes"), {
  withDeterminer: false
});
const result2 = format(moment.duration(1, "minutes"));

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See my answer above - turns out moment can handle it